# Execute code every second with only the current time?

Tags: java, algorithm

How can i execute code every second when only using the current time? (*no extra variables*, it doesn't have the be exactly every second, I'm quite happy with a variation between 800 to 1200 ms)

I did try:

```
//code repeated every 30-100ms
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) == 0) { //execute code
```

But this doesn't work, cause the chance that currentTimeMillis can be exactly divided by 1000 is not very high.

Any bright ideas on the subject?

[edit] please note my "no extra variables" remark. Let me explain a bit better:
i need to put this code in a place where i only have a long value indicating the unix time since 1970 (the value of currentTimeMillis). I can't remember anything, nor can i save extra variables that can be accessed the next time my code is executed. It's a special case.

Comment: Is there other code here that has to be run more frequently? Or is `Thread.sleep(1000)` sufficient for your situation?

Comment: "no extra variables" why not? What other core language features cannot arbitrarily be used?

Comment: Does my solution work for you or is there a problem with it?

Comment: @TinusTate `if ((System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) == 0) {` compiles to the same bytecode as `long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); if (currentTime % 1000 == 0) {`. "No extra variables" doesn't mean the code doesn't store things; only that you don't have an explicit name for them.

Comment: I'm gonna hazard another guess: whatever he is writing is instantiated, invoked once, and killed by his environment. So though you are correct, @AndyTurner, the "extra variable" won't be around the next time through this section of the code.

Comment: Further, he only gets one `Runnable` or whatever it is, and it gets invoked in the 30-100ms timeframe. But _this particular `if` block_ should only happen once every second.

Comment: "no extra variables"? You want it repeated every # (m)s. That isn't even possible without "extra variables". The most basic method to achieve this is Peter's solution below: `while(true){ Thread.Sleep(1000); }`. Please be more specific about what you mean with "no extra variables". You've stated that it isn't allowed with almost any answer given, but please give us some examples of what IS allowed..

Comment: every java method is located in a class, since you're modifying the method you are able to modify the class, why can't you have a field in a class to store last execution time?

Comment: I actually like the question, I just think it needs some more editing.

Comment: Why don't you tell us more about the constraints you're working in? You don't need to necessarily tell us about platform or whatever, especially if it's sensitive in some way. Just tell us the form, so to speak, within which your code is supposed to work.

Comment: What you're asking can't be done within the constraints given because you need to store a flag indicating whether the method has executed within the current time period. And you also have to clear that flag every second. Now, if you could store the time that the method was last executed . . .

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to use `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Future future = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When you no longer need it, you can cancel execution

```
future.cancel(true);
```

Comment: "no extra variables" as noted in my question ;-)

Comment: @TinusTate do you need a solution, or you just want to puzzle us? If second, then i'm not sure that stackoverflow is a right place to do it.

Comment: Agreed with AdamSkywalker.

Comment: not sure what no extra variables means.  ScheduledExecutorService is the way I would do this in real code.  Maybe you've got a contrived problem you have to solve?

Comment: All answers posted are completely right under normal circumstances, no doubt about that. But i have a bit of a special case with special requirements. Maybe i should have paid better attention to this when writing my question though.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(true) {
  //execute your code here
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: "no extra variables" as noted in my question ;-)

Comment: I don't see any extra variables here, @TinusTate. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do this would be to check that we are in the time window, perform the action and then use `Thread.sleep` long enough to ensure we are out of the time window.

```
private static final long WINDOW = 200;

void doItOncePerSecond(long time) throws InterruptedException {
    // Check the time.
    if ((time % 1000) / WINDOW == 0) {
        // Do your work.
        System.out.println("Now!! " + time + " - " + (time % 1000));
        // Wait long enopugh to be out of the window.
        Thread.sleep(WINDOW - (time % 1000));
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long t;
    while ((t = System.currentTimeMillis()) - start < 10000) {
        doItOncePerSecond(t);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Beyond that you may need to persist a value in some other way - perhaps use a socket to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This if statement would do it as per you request (between 800ms and 1200ms) but it is very inefficient and my previous answer or some of the other answers would be a lot better at doing what you want

```
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) < 200 || (System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) > 800) {

}
```

or since you code is repeated roughly every 30-100 ms you can use

```
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) < 100|| (System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000) > 900) {

}
```

Comment: "no extra variables" as noted in my question ;-)

Comment: @TinusTate I edited answer to give you it in the form you want but it is so inefficient

Comment: i haven't replied yet, cause i'm going to first test it, but on first sight it looks promising.

Comment: The danger with this approach is that your _once per second_ code could execute multiple times in the same window.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I agree but this is how the OP wanted it

Comment: No @Dan, he wants it to run just once every 800-1200 ms. With this approach, if `t` is `currentTimeMillis` is a multiple of 1000 plus, say, 1, then 30 ms later it still satisfies the condition. You'll end up executing twice in the same 30 ms time slice.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom If he could say it executed the time check executed once every x ms it would be a lot easier but if he wants to use a single if statement and doesn't have an exact time on how often his check executes then that would be a risk the OP would have to take. Unless the OP uses a more efficient method which are mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Timer for this, but you can't do this scheduled operation without defining extra variable or it will be in infinity mode.

You can try this:

```
new Timer().schedule(task, delay, period);
```

Comment: "no extra variables" as noted in my question ;-)

Comment: `task` can be an anonymous inner class containing the code to be run; no need for a variable. `delay` can be a constant, e.g. 1000. `period` is TimeUnit.SECONDS or some such idea. No extra variables.

Comment: If author of the post tries to execute repeated block in"if" statement, I think  , we can't help him :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get seconds and use it the way you would like to ...

```
long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does something every 1 second

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("a second has passed");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```